# The number of pairwise non-similar linear transformations with the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Question: What is the maximum number of pairwise non-similar linear transformations on a three-dimensional vector space, each of which has the characteristic polynomial $x^3$?

So far I have managed to get some non-similar transformations but I do not know how to use Jordan Form (this question is related to the Jordan From) and do not know how to proceed actaully. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix $A$ has characteristic polynomial $x^3$, then it has only one eigenvalue, i.e. $0$ with algebraic multiplicity $3$.

There are three possibilities, depending on the geometric multiplicity of $0$. If it's $3$, then your matrix is similar to
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

If it's $2$, then your matrix is similar to
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

If it's $1$, then your matrix is similar to
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
And there are no other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I should have gotten this, not complicated at all.